# socket.io request information from API but wait for response before emitting data to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, socket.io, es6-promise

I am building out an app which started as a node project. I am able to run my JS via scripts in the `package.json` and log stuff to the terminal.

I am now trying to plug in `sockets.io` to send data to the client.

I want to emit a message to the client only after my api call has finished (and I am importing this from another file).

This is my server.js

```
import { retrieveProjectDetails } from '../index.js';

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('server: a user connected');

  socket.on('getProjectDetails', (data) => {
    console.log('server: getProjectDetails: ' + data);

    io.emit('sendProjectDetails', (responseData) => {
      responseData = retrieveProjectDetails(); // This is emitting before the API call has been received. 
      console.log(`server: data: ${responseData}`);
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('server: user disconnected');
  });

});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on: ${PORT}`));
```

My client.js

```
const getProjectDetails = document.querySelector('.getProjectDetails');
const details = document.querySelector('.details');

getProjectDetails.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const target = new Date();
  socket.emit('getProjectDetails', target);
});

socket.on('sendProjectDetails', (data) => {
  details.textContent = JSON.stringify('received' + data, null, 4);
  console.log('client: sendProjectDetails was sent from the server');
  console.log(data);
});
```

index.js (in the root)

```
const getProject = () => {
  return apiRoot.get().execute();
};

// Retrieve Project information and output the result to the log
const retrieveProjectDetails = (data) => {
  getProject()
    .then(response => {
      data = response;
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

I am assuming I need either some callback function, or an await method (although I prefer working with promises) but as I am importing the function externally I am not sure how to wrap it using `.then()` or some other deferred method. Or maybe there is a way I can modify my `retrieveProjectDetails` function.

If you need more info (html markup, console logs etc.) just holler.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning `getProject` from `retrieveProjectDetails`, so that it returns a promise:

```
const retrieveProjectDetails = (data) => {
    return getProject()
        .then(response => {
        //...
```

and then call it first, and then emit data from the callback:

```
socket.on('getProjectDetails', (data) => {

    console.log('server: getProjectDetails: ' + data);

    retrieveProjectDetails(data).then(responseData => {

        console.log(`server: data: ${responseData}`);

        io.emit('sendProjectDetails', responseData);

    });

});
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.